# FLANN in opencv runs too slow

Tags: opencv, flann

I have a set of point cloub(number of point cloub≈2million). I would like to find the nearest k neighbor for each point within the point cloub. I did something like this

```
flann::Index flann_index(data_m, flann::KDTreeIndexParams(),cvflann::FLANN_DIST_EUCLIDEAN);// create the object of flann
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPointsInPointCloub; i++){
    flann_index.knnSearch(data_m.row(i), indices, dists,num_of_knn); //each row is a new set of point in 3D
    ..//save the results "dist" and "indices" in somewhere else
}
```

But this runs very slow. Within the for loop, it runs 1000 times for 20 seconds which is very slow. Am I use it wrongly? Or are there any method so that I can speed it up?

Update: 
The query point that I need to search is exactly the point used to construct the tree, I need to find the nearest k neighbor for each of the point within the tree thus I take the point from each row of the data and perform a knnSearch.

Comment: k-NN algorithms can suffer from what is known as the "*curse of dimensionality*" and can have a worst case time bound of *O(kN^(1-1/k))*. If your point cloud is virtually random, there may not be much you can do to speed up the search. As you are going through each of the 2 million points or so and then doing a knnSearch, you are creating a nested loop that will run in superlinear time. Without seeing all of the code, it is hard to determine what optimizations can be done to speed up your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was having similar issues recently. Here are some ideas:

First, make sure you are in **release mode**. Unoptimized code can seriously affect performance. My most recent test showed an improvement of 70x after a switch from debug to release code.

Second, you are using the default value for **flann::KDTreeIndexParams()**, which is 4 trees. For speed you can reduce this to 1. This may reduce accuracy, but could help in performance.

Third, at least in recent versions of OpenCV there is a fifth parameter for the knnSearch function, namely **SearchParams()**. Its constructor's first parameter, which "specifies the number of times the tree(s) in the index should be recursively traversed", can be modified to balance performance with accuracy. See the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html) for details.

Fourth, it seems you are searching for the neighbors of one query point at a time. Try running with **several query points at a time**. The return parameters "indices" and "dists" will be matrices where each row r represents the neighbors of the point at index r (and the first element of each row represents the query point itself).

Finally, if this is still not fast enough, perhaps check out the KdTree implementation in [VCG ibrary](http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/vcglib/). So far I've seen release mode performance gains of > 2x over OpenCV's FLANN. You can also try parallelizing, though I would only go down this road once you've eked out as much performance as possible from your non-parallel version.

Comment: Actually I would like to do perform a statistical _outlier removal just like the one in PCL [link](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/statistical_outlier.php)

Thats why I need to construct a kd-tree, select each element within the tree and perfrom KNN search on that.

Comment: Your original question was about how to improve the performance of OpenCV's flann::knnSearch implementation, while your update is more about how to use knnSearch in a statistical outlier removal algorithm, which is a somewhat different question. Unless I misunderstood the intent of the update, it's probably best to break it off into its own question to keep things focused.

Comment: OK, I will make it specific.

Comment: How should I change the dimension of the "indices" and "dists" if I have several query points?

Comment: Take a look at the Matrix class. Upon construction you supply your data, and the number of rows and columns. Note that you allocate your data elsewhere, which means you have to take care to free it afterwards too (I just used std::vector and then passed a pointer to the first element). For the indices and dists matrices, there should be a row per query point, and then a column per neighbor. 
See [FLANN manual](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/uploads/FLANN/flann_manual-1.6.pdf) for some examples.

Comment: +1 for switching from Debug to Release. The exec. time went from 2:43m to 12s for searchRadius called for 1M points (for PCL's implementation of kdtree also based on FLANN).